# Program type already present: org.tensorflow.Graph$Reference

Tags: android, gradle, tensorflow

I updated my Android Studio to 3.1.2, my app gradle looks as follows:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.8.0-rc0'
}
```

Trying to build gives me following error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.tensorflow.Graph$Reference","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:...
```

If someone could give me a hint where to search or how to fix would be really appreciated. I tried updating tensorflow to 1.8.0-rc1, didn't change a thing.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Glide version, and importing automatically from Project Structure?

Comment: Try running `gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` and see whether you have more than one version of a Tensor Flow library in the list.

Comment: can this happen if I already have a jar file in my lib-folder: libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar or other similar name in your project, which would conflict with your setting, "implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.x.x'"

Just delete the jar file, and works for me.